# Print the login shell of the current user in Python

Tags: python

How can i print the login shell of the current user in Python.

Can i do this with the OS module from Python & with the getlogin() function?
Can someone give me a hint to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.environ` and print out `SHELL` variable as follows:

```
from os import environ
print(environ['SHELL'])
```